# Unable to extend Orders Rest Api of Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, ce-1.9.0.1, rest-api

I am trying to extend Orders rest api in magento. For e.g To create a new update method. For doing this, I have created a new class in the local copy:
The file I am trying to override is :
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Api2\Order.php

But when I try to access the new method then I get a "Resource method not implemented" error message. I believe, the rewrite does not work in this case.

Similarly, I attempted to rewrite products rest api but over there rewrite method works correctly.

Just for your reference, I have pasted the code for Update Orders Rest Api below.

1. \app\code\local\MyModulename\Sales\Model\Api2\Order.php

   ```
   class MyModulename_Sales_Model_Api2_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Api2_Order
   {

       protected function _update(array $data)
       {
         echo 'in update function';
       }    
   }
   ```
2. \app\code\local\MyModulename\Sales\etc\api2.xml
   [image]
3. app\code\local\MyModulename\Sales\etc\config.xml
   [image]

Please note, this module is in active mode.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. the file which needs to be extended is

app\code\local\MyModule\Sales\Model\Api2\Order\Rest\Admin\V1.php

and rewrite tag has to be rewritten for this class.

Similarly for customer modifications will be required in

app\code\local\MyModule\Sales\Model\Api2\Order\Rest\Customer\V1.php